# Go 'Can't Find Import'

Tags: go, dependency-management

I'm attempting to incorporate Heroku's `log-shuttle` library (https://github.com/heroku/log-shuttle) into a Go project I'm working on. The tool is primarily designed to be run as an independent binary, but I'm hoping to integrate it in a different way in my tool.

So I get the library:

```
$ go get github.com/heroku/log-shuttle
$ ls $GOPATH/src/github.com/heroku/log-shuttle/
  batcher.go       Godeps ...
  ...
```

which returns successfully. Then I try to import the library:

```
package myPackage

import (
  "github.com/heroku/log-shuttle"
  "fmt"
  "log"
)
...
```

Great. But now I go to `go build` and...

```
$ go build
# github.com/<my project>
logWriter/log_shuttle_writer.go:5: can't find import: "github.com/heroku/log-shuttle"
```

I have my `GOPATH` set correctly (I believe):

```
$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/jeff/go/"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
TERM="dumb"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

And the package is installed and built, but it doesn't want to import. As you can see, there are non non-ASCII chars in the package path (though the hyphen is non-alpha-numeric), and I can't find any more info about what could be causing this problem.

Not sure how it would matter, but I am using `godep` to try to manage my dependencies.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[github.com/heroku/log-shuttle](https://github.com/heroku/log-shuttle) is a `main` package, not an importable library, meaning it's meant to be compiled and run as a binary.

Comment: Thanks. So if I fork, I'd want the code to reside in some package other than `main` and then I could access the exported functions?

Is there a general "best practice" for avoiding these problems so that your package can both be a runnable `main` but also imported by others?

Comment: If you want to be able to import your library, you put all the functionality in a non-main package, and then have a simple main package that imports and runs it.